# strange operator in c++ code

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I am looking at a c++ code and I find a statement like the following

```
BS_Id1 = (1./2) * BS_Id2;
```

I don't have access to all the libraries yet. Any idea on what are the possible explanations for this "./"?

Comment: @Hulk nice catch. I really need to get some coffee before I log on so early in the morning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not an operator. it's the `double` literal `1.0` divided by 2. If the decimals are zero, you can omit them, and only have the decimal point.

Comment: Although why that notation was chosen over `0.5` is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 3):

Writing `1.` is a way of expressing 1 as a floating point `double` rather than an integer. So the period is not acting as an operator in this case.

You need to do this as 1 / 2 is carried out in integer arithmetic; and, as such, will be truncated to zero.

In promoting at least one of the literals to floating point, the operation is carried out in floating point; so the result will be 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an operator. It's a division between `1.` and `2`.

The dot makes the compiler treating the `1` as a `double` instead of a `int` (which `1` is interpreted as) so that the result isn't the quotient of the euclidian division between two `int`s.

Here, `1./2` yields `0.5`, while `1/2` would have yielded `0`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an operator; the `.` is part of the previous token:

```
1. / 2
```

A `.` on the end of a numerical literal indicates that it's floating-point (type `double`), not an integer; so this means that the expression uses floating-point division to give the result `0.5` with type `double`. Without it, integer division would give the result zero, with type `int`.

In any event, if (as I guess) both variables are integers, the expression is almost certainly better written as

```
BS_Id1 = BS_Id2 / 2;
```

If floating-point arithmetic is actually desired, then either of these would be less confusing:

```
BS_Id1 = BS_Id2 / 2.0;
BS_Id1 = BS_Id2 * 0.5;
```

Comment: Re: your rewrite, are you sure they're the same with respect to floating point imprecisions?

Comment: @Angew: No, but any effects of those imprecisions are almost certainly bugs, unless the code is doing something insane. I suspect the `Id` values are integers, and the intention is to divide by two. I could be completely wrong of course - there's plenty of insane code out there.

Comment: If, for some insane reason, `BS_Id2` is an integral type while `BS_Id1` is a floating point type, your suggestion gives different behaviour. Can I suggest `BS_Id2 / 2.0`?

Answer (score 0):

`1.` is a floating point literal and it is `double` since it does not have a suffix and so this part of the expression `(1./2)` might be more clear like this:

```
(1.0/2)
```

But they are functionally identical. If we look at the grammar for a floating literals from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `2.14.4` *Floating literals* we see the following:

```
fractional-constant:
  digit-sequenceopt. digit-sequence
  digit-sequence .                    <-- 1. fits this part of the grammar
```

Answer (score 0):

See here

```
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$ cat main.cpp 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double x, y;  
  x = 1/2;
  y = 1./2;
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;
}
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$ r
0
0.5
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$
```

"1." is in a token, not "./"